# Pyside install fails (Python 2.7.4)

Tags: python, pip, pyside

I just upgraded to Ubuntu 13.04 (beta) and I'm getting an error when trying to install pyside into a Virtualenv (python 2.7.4) using pip:

```
error: Failed to locate the Python library /usr/lib/libpython2.7.so.1
```

Anyone have any ideas? I've tried previous versions as well as the dev version, still no luck.

**EDIT: Console Log for post_install**

```
(monster)tony@tonyubuntu:~/Downloads/pyside-setup$ python pyside_postinstall.py -install
PySide package found in /home/tony/Downloads/pyside-setup/PySide...
Patched rpath in /home/tony/Downloads/pyside-setup/PySide/QtUiTools.so to /home/tony/Downloads/pyside-setup/PySide.
Patched rpath in /home/tony/Downloads/pyside-setup/PySide/QtCore.so to /home/tony/Downloads/pyside-setup/PySide.
Patched rpath in /home/tony/Downloads/pyside-setup/PySide/QtTest.so to /home/tony/Downloads/pyside-setup/PySide.
Patched rpath in /home/tony/Downloads/pyside-setup/PySide/QtHelp.so to /home/tony/Downloads/pyside-setup/PySide.
Patched rpath in /home/tony/Downloads/pyside-setup/PySide/QtXml.so to /home/tony/Downloads/pyside-setup/PySide.
Patched rpath in /home/tony/Downloads/pyside-setup/PySide/QtSql.so to /home/tony/Downloads/pyside-setup/PySide.
Patched rpath in /home/tony/Downloads/pyside-setup/PySide/QtGui.so to /home/tony/Downloads/pyside-setup/PySide.
Patched rpath in /home/tony/Downloads/pyside-setup/PySide/shiboken to /home/tony/Downloads/pyside-setup/PySide.
Patched rpath in /home/tony/Downloads/pyside-setup/PySide/QtDeclarative.so to /home/tony/Downloads/pyside-setup/PySide.
Patched rpath in /home/tony/Downloads/pyside-setup/PySide/QtSvg.so to /home/tony/Downloads/pyside-setup/PySide.
Patched rpath in /home/tony/Downloads/pyside-setup/PySide/QtNetwork.so to /home/tony/Downloads/pyside-setup/PySide.
Patched rpath in /home/tony/Downloads/pyside-setup/PySide/QtScriptTools.so to /home/tony/Downloads/pyside-setup/PySide.
Patched rpath in /home/tony/Downloads/pyside-setup/PySide/QtScript.so to /home/tony/Downloads/pyside-setup/PySide.
Patched rpath in /home/tony/Downloads/pyside-setup/PySide/QtWebKit.so to /home/tony/Downloads/pyside-setup/PySide.
Patched rpath in /home/tony/Downloads/pyside-setup/PySide/phonon.so to /home/tony/Downloads/pyside-setup/PySide.
Patched rpath in /home/tony/Downloads/pyside-setup/PySide/QtXmlPatterns.so to /home/tony/Downloads/pyside-setup/PySide.
Patched rpath in /home/tony/Downloads/pyside-setup/PySide/QtOpenGL.so to /home/tony/Downloads/pyside-setup/PySide.
PySide package successfully installed in /home/tony/Downloads/pyside-setup/PySide...
```

Comment: You're using a beta Ubuntu version, so not everything is going to work smoothly. What does `ls -1 /usr/lib/libpython2.7.so*` output?

Comment: ls: cannot access /usr/lib/libpython2.7.so*: No such file or directory

Comment: To add, libpython2.7 is installed, the file just doesn't exist. The closest i've found is: libpyglib-2.0-python2.7.so.0 (which does exist).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm author of pyside setup scripts.
I will test the build scripts on ubuntu 13.04.
Are you using 32 or 64bit version ?

**Update 1**:
Fixed the pyside build scripts for Ubuntu 13.04.
You need to clone the latest pyside-setup from git repo and build as follows (note --qmake param):

```
$ git clone https://github.com/PySide/pyside-setup.git pyside-setup
$ cd pyside-setup
$ python setup.py bdist_egg --qmake=/usr/bin/qmake-qt4
```

and then install the PySide distribution as follows:

```
$ sudo easy_install dist/PySide-1.1.3dev-py2.7.egg
$ sudo python pyside_postinstall.py -install
```

I have not used pip because i prefer to build the egg once and install many times as needed
Regards
R.

Comment: Using 64bit. I upgraded, so it's not a fresh install. (from 12.10)

Comment: i will use fresh install. On 12.10 is pyside installed OK ?

Comment: I'm also attempting to install to a virtualenv (using virtualenvwrapper).

Going to see if I can install without the virtualenv (will report back).

Comment: Same problem, doesn't appear to be a virtualenv issue (which makes sense, considering the file it's looking for doesn't exist, but better to be sure)

Comment: Just saw your edit, pyside worked perfectly on 12.10, but when I upgraded to 13.04 I wasn't able to install to a new virtualenv. It still was installed on my main python install, but I have since removed it, in an attempt to fix the problem.

Comment: this is the problem: libpython2.7.so was moved to /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu folder, on ubuntu 12.10 it was in /usr/lib. I will fix the setup scripts...

Comment: Perfect! The install seems to have worked (I haven't thoroughly tested). I did get this when using easy_install on the .egg, not sure if it's relevant to you. 
____________________________________________________
    Extracting PySide-1.1.3dev-py2.7.egg to      /home/tony/.virtualenvs/monster/lib/python2.7/site-packages
    File "/home/tony/.virtualenvs/monster/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PySide-1.1.3dev-py2.7.egg/pysideuic/port_v3/proxy_base.py", line 26
    class ProxyBase(metaclass=ProxyType):
                             ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: you can ignore these warnings, they are related to python 3 code which is not used on python 2. btw you can use pip to install pyside without problems, but pip does not support prebuild distributions, it allways install from source. Regards. R.

Comment: Hrmm, I attempted to install with pip first and it failed. 

I tried from pypi, and the github repo for both PySide and PySide-setup.

Easy install worked great though.

Comment: Perhaps this is a separate issue though and shouldn't be on this SO Question.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "monster.py", line 8, in <module>
    from PySide import QtCore, QtGui
ImportError: libpyside-python2.7.so.1.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Doh! Doesn't seem to work!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28466/discussion-between-moreisee-and-rlacko)

Comment: I've re marked your question as the correct answer as I realized you infact did answer the question (You got it to install). 

Will open up a new question for the next half. Thanks!

Comment: you need to call the **post install script** to avoid errors like: ImportError: libpyside-python2.7.so.1.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
**$ python pyside_postinstall.py -install**

Comment: very.. odd.. I've just found if i open python from the git clone directory (pyside_setup), I don't get the error, if I run python from any other directory, I do..

Comment: can you send me the console output of **$ python pyside_postinstall.py -install** ?

Comment: i see where is the problem, wait a moment i will check this on virtual machine

Comment: please run the following command and post me the output: **sudo python2.7 /usr/local/bin/pyside_postinstall.py -install**

Comment: hi, the pos-install script is now really fixed. please pull latest version from github and try rebuild and reinstall the PySide distribution

Comment: So if PySide v1.1.2 from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PySide is broken, how can they be notified?  (A few days ago, I downloaded and built it on Ubuntu 12.04, it seemed to install but then 'import PySide' fails with a message like 'undefined symbol in ...so'.  The answer given here restored my PySide installation.)

Comment: All fixed are in github repo and were not published to PyPI. Until the new release, please clone PySide setup scripts from github repository.

Comment: When i do these steps, it seems to work fine up until the `python pyside_postinstall.py -install` step, the first time i got a whole load of `Patching rpath` lines, then `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pyside_postinstall.py", line 236, in install_posix
    from PySide import QtCore
ImportError: /home/will/python-modules/lib/python2.6/site-packages/PySide-1.3.0dev-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg/PySide/libpyside-python2.6.so.1.2: undefined symbol: _ZN9QMetaType15registerTypedefEPKci`. If i try again i get a seg fault. It's scientific linux 6.4, and i don't have root.

Answer (score 1):

Another way:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so.1 /usr/lib/ && pip install PySide
```