# Installing PySide under Python 3 virtualenv on Ubuntu

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, installation, shared-libraries, pyside

I get the following error due to a missing library:

```
error: Failed to locate the Python library /usr/local/lib/libpython3.3m.so
```

I've tried installing pyside from the git HEAD as per this SO [Pyside install fails (Python 2.7.4)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16074801/pyside-install-fails-python-2-7-4)

but still fails due to:

```
/usr/local/lib/libpython3.3m.a: could not read symbols: Bad value
```

The file `/usr/local/lib/libpython3.3m.a` exists on my system. Any ideas?

Comment: I have this exact same problem, have you found a solution?

Comment: sadly, no. This was encountered when trying to get IPython GUI in Python 3.3, i've found that it's much more flexible to use IPython in the terminal (+tmux) and export pngs, so i didn't purse this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This almost certainly happens because your Python installation has a *static* library under `$PREFIX/lib`, but no *shared* libraries. That is, there is a `libpython3.3m.a` file, but no `libpython3.3m.so` file(s).

To fix this, recompile Python with the `--enable-shared` flag.