# PySide code completion in PyCharm

Tags: python, pyside, pycharm

I have noticed that code completion for PySide does not seem to work for me with Pycharm. Code completion works in IPython which makes me believe its possible to get this working. Has anyone managed to get this working?

I find that coding without autocomplete limits how fast I can learn to develop with PySide as I cannot "browse" through available classes.

I have tried invalidating the cache / restarting but this does not seem to work.

```
Ubuntu 14.04
Pycharm 3.4
Python 2.7
Installing PySide through pip
```

Comment: For me it works right out of the box wiht PyCharm 3.4 and PySide on Python 2.7 on Windows. So I guess this is not a universal problem and you should indicate your specific circumstances.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally managed to solve the issue by uninstalling PySide from pip and installing the github dev version:

```
git clone https://github.com/PySide/pyside-setup.git pyside-setup
cd pyside-setup
python setup.py bdist_egg --qmake=/usr/bin/qmake-qt4

sudo easy_install dist/PySide-1.1.3dev-py2.7.egg
sudo python pyside_postinstall.py -install
```

Credit goes to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16074801/pyside-install-fails-python-2-7-4).

Answer (score 0):

For my case (Python 3.7, Pyside2), it was solved by updating the Project Interpreter to point to the correct Python version. Previously it was set to "No Interpreter".

[image]